# Scheduling doesn't work due to caching?

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache, nginx

I'm using W3 Total Cache and Nginx with Varnish, and I'm very happy with the speed. However, I noticed that when I schedule a post, the post doesn't get automatically posted when I'm a *visitor*. When I'm logged in as an *admin* and I reload the page it correctly posts the new content.

Varnish config (default.vcl)

```
#
# Varnish 3 configuration for Wordpress
#
# On Debian OS:  /etc/varnish/default.vcl
#
# Nicolas Hennion (aka) Nicolargo
#

# Set the default backend (Nginx server for me)
backend default {
    # My Nginx server listen on IP address 127.0.0.1 and TCP port 8080
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    # Increase guru timeout
    # http://vincentfretin.ecreall.com/articles/varnish-guru-meditation-on-timeout
    .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
}

# Forbidden IP ACL
acl forbidden {
    "41.194.61.2"/32;
    "192.54.144.229"/32;
}

# Purge ACL
acl purge {
    # Only localhost can purge my cache
    "127.0.0.1";
    "localhost";
}

# This function is used when a request is send by a HTTP client (Browser) 
sub vcl_recv {
    # Block the forbidden IP addresse
    if (client.ip ~ forbidden) {
            error 403 "Forbidden";
    }

    # Only cache the following sites
    #if ((req.http.host ~ "(blog.nicolargo.com)") || (req.http.host ~ "(blogtest.nicolargo.com)")) { 
    if ((req.http.host ~ "(blog.nicolargo.com)")) { 
        set req.backend = default; 
    } else { 
        return (pass); 
    }

    # Compatibility with Apache format log
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
        if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
                set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
        }
     }

    # Normalize the header, remove the port (in case you're testing this on various TCP ports)
    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");

    # Allow purging from ACL
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        # If not allowed then a error 405 is returned
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            error 405 "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests.";
        }   
        # If allowed, do a cache_lookup -> vlc_hit() or vlc_miss()
        return (lookup);
    }

    # Post requests will not be cached
    if (req.request == "POST") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # --- Wordpress specific configuration

    # Did not cache the RSS feed
    if (req.url ~ "/feed") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Blitz hack
        if (req.url ~ "/mu-.*") {
                return (pass);
        }


    # Did not cache the admin and login pages
    if (req.url ~ "/wp-(login|admin)") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Remove the "has_js" cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp test cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^ *$") {
            unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # Cache the following files extensions 
    if (req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e)?g|swf|ico)") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # Normalize Accept-Encoding header and compression
    # https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/vary.html
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        # Do no compress compressed files...
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
                remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
                set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
                set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Check the cookies for wordpress-specific items
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_" || req.http.Cookie ~ "comment_") {
        return (pass);
    }
    if (!req.http.cookie) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # --- End of Wordpress specific configuration

    # Did not cache HTTP authentication and HTTP Cookie
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
        # Not cacheable by default
        return (pass);
    }

    # Cache all others requests
    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    return (pipe);
}

sub vcl_pass {
    return (pass);
}

# The data on which the hashing will take place
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # If the client supports compression, keep that in a different cache
        if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
            hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hit {
    # Allow purges
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged.";
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_miss {
    # Allow purges
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
        purge;
        error 200 "Purged.";
    }

    return (fetch);
}

# This function is used when a request is sent by our backend (Nginx server)
sub vcl_fetch {
    # For static content strip all backend cookies
    if (req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e?)g)|swf|ico") {
        unset beresp.http.cookie;
    }

    # A TTL of 30 minutes
    set beresp.ttl = 1800s;

    return (deliver);
}

# The routine when we deliver the HTTP request to the user
# Last chance to modify headers that are sent to the client
sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) { 
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "cached";
    } else {
        set resp.http.x-Cache = "uncached";
    }

    # Remove some headers: PHP version
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;

    # Remove some headers: Apache version & OS
    unset resp.http.Server;

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_init {
    return (ok);
}

sub vcl_fini {
    return (ok);
}
```

nginx (examplesite.conf)

```
server {
    ## Your website name goes here.
    server_name examplesite.com www.examplesite.com;
    ## Your only path reference.
    root /var/www/examplesite.com;
    listen 8080;
    ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    ##set body size
    client_max_body_size 20M;


    include conf.d/drop;

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/dev/shm/php-fpm-www.sock;


        }


# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache cache
location ~ /wp-content/w3tc/pgcache.*html$ {
    add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding, Cookie";
}
location ~ /wp-content/w3tc/pgcache.*gzip$ {
    gzip off;
    types {}
    default_type text/html;
    add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding, Cookie";
    add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
}
# END W3TC Page Cache cache
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
gzip on;
gzip_types text/css application/x-javascript text/x-component text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon;
location ~ \.(css|js|htc)$ {
}
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
expires 1y;
log_not_found off;
}
location ~ \.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$ {
}
location ~ \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
}
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
rewrite ^(.*\/)?w3tc_rewrite_test$ $1?w3tc_rewrite_test=1 last;
set $w3tc_rewrite 1;
if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($http_host !~ "examplesite.com") {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
set $w3tc_rewrite3 1;
if ($request_uri ~* "(\/wp-admin\/|\/xmlrpc.php|\/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail)\.php|\/feed\/|wp-.*\.php|index\.php)") {
    set $w3tc_rewrite3 0;
}
if ($request_uri ~* "(wp\-comments\-popup\.php|wp\-links\-opml\.php|wp\-locations\.php)") {
    set $w3tc_rewrite3 1;
}
if ($w3tc_rewrite3 != 1) {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($http_cookie ~* "(comment_author|wp\-postpass|wordpress_\[a\-f0\-9\]\+|wordpress_logged_in)") {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($http_user_agent ~* "(W3\ Total\ Cache/0\.9\.2\.4)") {
    set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
set $w3tc_ua "";
set $w3tc_ref "";
set $w3tc_ssl "";
set $w3tc_enc "";
if ($http_accept_encoding ~ gzip) {
    set $w3tc_enc _gzip;
}
set $w3tc_ext "";
if (-f "$document_root/wp-content/w3tc/pgcache/$request_uri/_index$w3tc_ua$w3tc_ref$w3tc_ssl.html$w3tc_enc") {
    set $w3tc_ext .html;
}
if ($w3tc_ext = "") {
  set $w3tc_rewrite 0;
}
if ($w3tc_rewrite = 1) {
    rewrite .* "/wp-content/w3tc/pgcache/$request_uri/_index$w3tc_ua$w3tc_ref$w3tc_ssl$w3tc_ext$w3tc_enc" last;
}
# END W3TC Page Cache core

}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wp_schedule_event](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) is only run when your site is visited and the scheduled time has past.  If varnish is serving a non expired cached page then your visitor is not hitting WordPress.

> Schedules a hook which will be executed by the WordPress actions core
>   on a specific interval, specified by you. The action will trigger when
>   someone visits your WordPress site, if the scheduled time has passed.
>   See the Plugin API for a list of hooks.

Eventually when your cache expires or is invalidated your wp_cron should fire when varnish rebuilds the cache.

Comment: Ok, to workaround this problem I fire the wp-cron from a crontab every 15 minutes. However, it' not clearing the cache, even though I did configure varnish cache refresh in W3 Total Cache. Is there a way to do this manually in cron aswell?